# Devise, CanCan and ActiveAdmin on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin, cancan

I keep getting an error trying to use ActiveAdmin in my Rails application with Devise and CanCan. The error is:

> CanCan::AuthorizationNotPerformed in Admin::FindingsController#index

This action failed the `check_authorization` because it does not `authorize_resource`. Add `skip_authorization_check` to bypass this check.

I've looked extensively and cannot find a solution that seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveAdmin authorize the request in a different way, you can't use `check_authorization` with ActiveAdmin.